# Will application pass FIPS certification if we use md5 only to calculate unique values?

Tags: security, hash, md5, fips

Our software has a functionality to calculate unique parts of some data.
To do that we use md5 hash function, store all hashes and eliminate those which are duplicated.
We do not use md5 for passwords hashing or in other security-critical use cases.
Will our software pass FIPS certification if we have only these use cases?

I know that md5 is not FIPS-approved algorithm, but as far as I know it is only critical when there are security risk, for example if someone is using it to hash passwords.

Comment: Ask yourself: What happens if a user manages to cause a hash collision?

Comment: To me that will be just a defect and not security issue. User data or private information will not be affected

Answer (score 0):

As per FIPS 140-2 compliance, it is strongly suggested to use only FIPS approved algorithms for digests that is listed in FIPS-180. I see you're not using it for passwords but FIPS never said that these algorithms are only meant for password hashes. Hence, MD5 should not be used in the entirety of application.